# Main function body doesn't detect call to overloaded variadic-templated function C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, variadic-functions, packing

I'm currently learning variadic template functions and parameter packing/unpacking.

This is my code,

```cpp
template<typename T, typename U> 
void my_insert(std::vector<int>& v, T& t) {
    int i;
    if (typeid(t).name() == typeid(const char*).name()) {
        i = stoi(t);
    }
    else if (typeid(t).name() == typeid(char).name()) {
        i = t - 48;
    }
    else if (typeid(t).name() == typeid(int).name()) {
        i = t;
    }
    else if (typeid(t).name() == typeid(double).name()) {
        i = static_cast<int>(round(t));
    }
    else if (typeid(t).name() == typeid(bool).name()) {
        if (t) i == 1;
        else i == 0;
    }
    else if (typeid(t).name() == typeid(std::vector<U>).name()) {
        int j = 0;
        while (j < t.size()) {
            my_insert(v, t[j]);
            ++j;
        }
    }
    else return;
    v.push_back(i);
}
template<typename T, typename U, typename ...Args>
void my_insert(std::vector<int>& v, T& t, Args&... args) {
    int i;
    if (typeid(t).name() == typeid(const char*).name()) {
        if (isdigit(t[0])) i = stoi(t);
        // else do nothing
    }
    else if (typeid(t).name() == typeid(char).name()) {
        i = t - 48;
    }
    else if (typeid(t).name() == typeid(int).name()) {
        i = t;
    }
    else if (typeid(t).name() == typeid(double).name()) {
        i = static_cast<int>(round(t));
    }
    else if (typeid(t).name() == typeid(bool).name()) {
        if (t) i == 1;
        else i == 0;
    }
    else if (typeid(t).name() == typeid(std::vector<U>).name()) {
        int j = 0;
        while (j < t.size()) {
            my_insert(v, t[j]);
            ++j;
        }
    }
    //else do nothing
    v.push_back(i);
    my_insert(args...);
}

int main() {

    std::vector<int> v; 

    my_insert(v, "123", "-8", 32, 3.14159, true, true, false, '5', "12.3");

    return 0;
}
```

ERROR : no instance of overloaded function my_insert matches the argument list

I don't understand what mistake I've made since for me the same exact implementation of the a `print()` function works with `{ cout << t << endl; print(args...); }` , w/ signature `<typename T, typename ...Args> void print(const T& t, const Args... args)`;

I know that a variadic function can be implemented with recursive calls non-variadic parameter overloaded versions of the same function. A so-called base case statement.

With all that being said, I'm unsure what it is that I'm doing incorrectly.

Comment: Please be more specific about the problem. Do you get a compilation error or unexpected behaviour and what are they?

Comment: The mistake you're making is using `typeid` on templated type variables. Why? Just call a suitable (overloaded/specialized) function that does what needs to be done for each type.

Answer (score 1):

Well... there are some problems in your code.

The blocking error is the template parameter `U`

```
template<typename T, typename U> 
void my_insert(std::vector<int>& v, T& t) 

template<typename T, typename U, typename ...Args>
void my_insert(std::vector<int>& v, T& t, Args&... args)
```

The compiler can't deduce it and calling the function

```
my_insert(v, "123", "-8", 32, 3.14159, true, true, false, '5', "12.3");
```

the `U` isn't explicated

I suppose that the idea is "if `T` is a `std::vector` of some type `U`, add all element of the vector". If I understand correctly, I suggest to add a different overloaded version of the function.

Other problems...

1) In a couple of points you write something as

```
    if (t) i == 1;  
    else i == 0;
```

It seems to me that your using operator `==` (comparison) instead of `=` (assignment).

General suggestion: enable the highest warning level to intercept this sort of trivial errors.

2) Your using `typeid`

```
if (typeid(t).name() == typeid(char).name())
```

to compare types.

Suggestion: use `std::is_same` instead

```
if ( std::is_same<T, char>::value )
```

3) The ground case of your recursion is a `my_insert()` function that is almost identical to the recursive version; the only differences are the absence of `Args...` argument and recursion call.

This is error prone because, if you modify one of the two version, you must remember to modify the other in the same way.

Suggestion: write a empty-and-do-nothing ground case; something as

```
void my_insert (std::vector<int> & v)
 {  }
```

4) you can't compile

```
i = stoi(t);
```

when `t` isn't a `char const *`

Analogous problems with other assignments.

The problem is that when you write [pseudocode]

```
if ( condition )
   statement_1;
else
   statement_2;
```

the compiler must compile both `statement_1` and `statement_2` also when know compile-time that `condition` is `true` or `false`.

To avoid the compilation of the unused statement, you have to use `if constexpr`.

So you have to write something as

```
   if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<T, char const *> )
      i = std::stoi(t);
   else if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<T, char> )
      i = t - 48;
   else if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<T, int> )
      i = t;
   else if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<T, double> )
      i = static_cast<int>(std::round(t));
   else if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<T, bool> )
      i = t;
```

Unfortunately, `if constexpr` is available only starting from C++17.

Before C++17, you have to write different overloaded functions.

5) calling `my_insert()` recursively, you have to remember the `v` vector

```
my_insert(args...); // <-- wrong! no v

my_insert(v, args...); // <-- correct
```

6) take in count that `"123"` is convertible to `char const *` but isn't a `char const *` (it's a `char const [4]`); so, instead of

```
if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<T, char const *> )
   i = std::stoi(t);
```

you can try with

```
if constexpr ( std::is_convertible_v<T, char const *> )
   i = std::stoi(t);
```

---

The following is a possible C++17 implementation of your code

```
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

void my_insert (std::vector<int> const &)
 { }

template <typename T, typename ... As>
void my_insert (std::vector<int> &, std::vector<T> const &, As const & ...);

template <typename T, typename ... As>
void my_insert (std::vector<int> & v, T const & t, As const & ... as)
 {
   int i{};

   if constexpr ( std::is_convertible_v<T, char const *> )
      i = std::stoi(t);
   else if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<T, char> )
      i = t - 48;
   else if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<T, int> )
      i = t;
   else if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<T, double> )
      i = static_cast<int>(std::round(t));
   else if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<T, bool> )
      i = t;
   // else ???

   v.push_back(i);

   my_insert(v, as...);
 }

template <typename T, typename ... As>
void my_insert (std::vector<int> & v, std::vector<T> const & t,
                As const & ... as)
 {
   for ( auto const & val : t )
      my_insert(v, val);

   my_insert(v, as...);
 }

int main ()
 {
   std::vector<int> v; 
   std::vector<char> u { '9', '8', '7' };

   my_insert(v, "123", "-8", 32, 3.14159, true, u, false, '5', "12.3");

   for ( auto const & val : v )
      std::cout << val << ' ';

   std::cout << std::endl;
 }
```